# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la fuente-tamaño (original) de AutoScale para evitar la baja resolución al usar el ejecutable del programa?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

He desarrollado unas clases y programas en C# en un equipo con una pantalla a una resolución de 1366 x 768. Ahora continúo con el desarrollo en otro equipo con una pantalla a una resolución de 2560 x 1600.

He estado programando para que la clase que genera forms y controles en tiempo de ejecución, adapte los tamaños de controles y fuentes aprovechando las resoluciones en cada equipo que se ejecute (su mejor resolución), teniendo en cuenta la resolución del equipo original, la resolución con la que se ejecute y el factor de escala gráfica del sistema. Ha sido un poco complejo pero en esa parte ya está casi terminada.

Pero por ahora solo aplica todo esto correctamente al ejecutarlo desde el IDE Visual Studio. Cuando ejecuto el .exe compilado fuera del VS, se genera el AutoScale, que no aprovecha la definición (del equipo) en el cual se esté ejecutando, sino que genera todo (controles y fuentes) en baja resolución : tamaño adaptado pero baja resolución.

Me gusaría saber como puedo regenerar la fuente de escalado original, para que cuando el AutoScale la tome, parta de la mayor resolución de este nuevo equipo, y no malogre el interfaz de la aplicación.

***Nota :*** para poder sacar la captura de la aplicación con la resolución inadecuada
he tenido que adecuar los valores de la programación propia para el escalado, porque de otro modo al aplicar el autoScaling sobre la programación de escalado
se salen los tamaños del rango valido. No obstante, la cuestión es la misma, porque esto es lo que hace el proceso de AutoScaling cuando se desarrolla el programa en menor resolución y luego se ejecuta en alta, mientras que la programación propia de escalado puede adaptar la resolución a cada configuración optimizando el aspecto. Creo que esto que necesito aplicar para esta cuestión podría tener que ver con la propiedad Form.AutoScaleBaseSize pero igual no se como manejarla.

Las capturas son fragmentos de una ventana porque el proyecto tiene una apariencia plana de diseño, y no quiero ponerla en un medio público.

***Resolución [Inadecuada] (AutoScaling) en formulario 2 foto 1 ...***

[image: ResoluciónInadecuada en formulario 2 foto 1.PNG]

---

***Resolución [Adecuada] (Adaptada, exec. en el IDE) en formulario 2 foto (2) 1 ...***

[image: ResoluciónAdecuada en formulario 2 foto 1.PNG]

He descubierto algunas cosas sobre esta cuestión. El programa funciona correctamente en el IDE con el hospedaje de Visual Studio. Fuera del proceso de hospedaje parece no adecuarse al escalado gráfico del sistema, en cuanto a la definición de fuentes y controles, en mi ordenador está en 250 %.

Al desactivar el hospedaje de Visual Studio en las propiedades del proyecto en el apartado Depuración, el programa adopta el mismo comportamiento que fuera del IDE con el ejecutable. Entonces me pregunto, ¿Existe la posibilidad de reproducir el comportamiento del interfaz con el hospedaje en el ejecutable?

Quiero añadir que, por lo que he leido, todo esto puede producirse debido a que WindowsForm no es vectorial, mientras que WPF si. Pero claro, no se si es posible portar el código a un proyecto de ese tipo, nunca he programado un WPF.

Hice la programación de adaptacion gráfica con el IDE, con hospedaje de VS, entonces la programación orientada a adaptar tamaños proporciones se aplica perfectamente, aunque lo ejecute en diferentes ordenadores o con escalas graficas diferentes. Sin el proceso de hospedaje, hace una especie de difuminado y altera las proporciones, parece un error del VS, al menos es la impresión que me da, no alcanzo a comprender por que se produce.

Comment: Puedes añadir el codigo que estas usnado para generar los forms dinamicos, asi recibiras mejores respuestas

Comment: Comprendo que en general es conveniente agregar el código en una duda, la cuestión es que, el código funciona de forma precisa, he estudiado el tema, y lo único que me falta, no está en el codigo, justamente. El AutoScaling hace algo así como lo que hace esta programación, pero si has desarrollado el código en baja o menor resolución, y luego lo pones en una mayor hace una especie de efecto lupa. Y solo quisiera saber como reiniciar la fuente de Autoescalado original, aquella que toma de referencia al crear la solución o aplicación. Gracias por la sugerencia igualmente.

Comment: Si crees que el problema no este en el codigo, podrias agregar una captura de pantalla con el comportamiento actual y quiza indicar cual seria el deseado

Answer (score 2):

Ya he resuelto la falla. El difuminado del ejecutable fuera del IDE, se provocaba al usar una **escala gráfica** de 250% (en el equipo nuevo a 2560 x 1600 ), visible sin el proceso de hospedaje de Visual Studio. Lo que provocaba el fallo era : una escala gráfica diferente de la recomendada.

¿Que hice para resolverlo?

1. Esablecer la escala gráfica a su nivel recomendado ( en este caso 200%, aplicar el nivel recomendado en tu equipo ) ( Configuración >> Sistema >> Cambiar el tamaño del texto, las aplicaciones y otros elementos: ... ).
2. Ajustar una óptima configuración (del Sistema Operativo) del tamaño de las fuentes ( Configuración >> Sistema >> [abajo] Configuración avanzada de la pantalla >> Opciones avanzadas del tamaño del texto y otros elementos >> Cambiar solo el tamaño del texto ).

También utilicé otra serie de ajustes en mi proyecto, de los valores en la programación para la optimización del interfaz de la aplicación segun la resolución y la escala grafica del equipo en que se ejecute. Ya no se genera el difuminado, las fuentes y controles se generan correctamente, definidos.

**Observo en base a la experiencia** : que los exe compilados con Visual Studio 2015, ejecutados fuera del IDE, basados en Forms, con una escala gráfica ( a nivel del Sistema Operativo ) diferente a la recomendada, presentan un difuminado y distorsión de las proporciones de fuentes y controles. Que se trata de algo añadido a lo que cabe esperar de la mera diferencia de resoluciones e incluso de la propia escala gráfica, pues todo esto estaba previsto y trazado en mi proyecto. Creo que ha de ser seguramente una inadaptación del IDE en proyectos basados en Forms respecto al parametro de escala gráfica ( del Sistema Operativo ).